# Search on more columns

Tags: php, sql, search

This is a program where you can search in a database.
But I would like to search on columns Postcode and Huisnummer. But everything I try does not work. Anyone an Idea

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index1.css" />
        <title>Inboedelwaarde op adres</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
        <form action="zoekadres.php" method="post"> 
        Postcode: <input type="text" name="term" /><br />       
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Zoek" />   
        </form>
    </p>
    </body>
</html>


<html lang="nl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Inboedelwaarde</title>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <?php      
        mysql_connect ("localhost", "root","")  or die (mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db ("inboedelmeter");
        $term = $_POST['term'];
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT Postcode, Huisnummer, Toevoeging, Inboedelwaarde 
                            FROM puntentotaal 
                            WHERE Postcode like '%$term%'");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  
            echo 'Postcode: '.$row['Postcode'];    
            echo '<br/> Huisnummer: '.$row['Huisnummer'];    
            echo '<br/> Toevoeging: '.$row['Toevoeging'];    
            echo '<br/> Uw inboedelwaarde is EURO € '.$row['Inboedelwaarde'];
            echo '<br/><br/>';
            }
                echo "<p><form action='adresbekijken.php' method='post'>
                        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Opnieuw zoeken'>"
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You know you have a BIG SQL injection hole there... right?

Comment: what do you see when you submit the form?

Comment: Then I get a result of every record with that Postcode but not Huisnummer

Comment: What do you mean with BIG SQL injection hole?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `WHERE Postcode like '%' . $term . '%'");`

Answer (score 0):

On the code

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT Postcode, Huisnummer, Toevoeging, Inboedelwaarde FROM puntentotaal WHERE Postcode like '%$term%'");
```

You're searching all the fields. Try to change it to "SELECT Postcode, Huisnummer WHERE Postcode like '%$term%'";".

So you're going to just search that collumns.

Comment: But then I got a eroor in
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){